# Error in source code for creating multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have written the below code in C# to create multiple thread (for ex 10 here)

```
ThreadStart MainThread = new ThreadStart(CallThread);
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    Thread ChildThread + Convert.ToString(i) = new Thread(MainThread);    
    ChildThread + Convert.ToString(i).Start();
}
```

it gives error `cannot resolve symble ChildThread` in 4th line and `Cannot resolve symbol Start` in 5th line.

Could someone help me out how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can't have dynamic name for variables

Comment: my requirement is i need to create dynamic no of threads, how can i do that

Comment: pls explain or source code for that pls

Comment: You could store them in a Dictionary with the key as your concatenation and the value as your thread

Comment: How about [using a thread pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt679040.aspx)?

Comment: Why are you even trying to use threads like this? You should be using `Task`, `async` and `await`

Answer (score 1):

You can''t concatenate data to make variable name in c#.

You could simulate the same behavior using a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<String, Thread> _threads = new Dictionary<String, Thread>(10);
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{   
    _threads.Add("ChildThread" + Convert.ToString(i),new Thread(MainThread) )
    _threads["ChildThread" + Convert.ToString(i)].Start();
}
```

**Edit**

On your second requirement you could pass a State to your Thread which could be a list of Files:

```
List<FileInfo> listOfFiles = //some way to get your files
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{   
    _threads.Add("ChildThread" + Convert.ToString(i),new Thread(MainThread) )
    _threads["ChildThread" + Convert.ToString(i)].Start( _listOfFiles.Skip(i*5).Take(5).ToList());
}
```

And in your CallThread function:

```
private void CallThread(Object state) {
    List<FileInfo> filesToProcess = state as List<FileInfo>;
    if(filesToProcess == null) return;
    foreach(FileInfo f in filesToProcess) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, it is working now. my next requirement is lets say a folder has 50 files, now assume i create 10 threads, the 1st thread should read files 1-5, 2nd thread should read files 6-10, 3rd thread should  read 11-15 and so on. can you help the logic how to implement this. thanks a lot for your prompt help

Comment: sorry, by mistake press entered,

Comment: Hi,string directoryPath = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("FILES_LOCATION");
            List<FileInfo> _listOfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);

Comment: Hi, as per your suggestion, i clubbed my code with your code, but it give error "cannot convert source type String[] to tartget type system.collection.gener......" pls see below code      string directoryPath = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("FILES_LOCATION");
            List<FileInfo> _listOfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath); pls help me to sort out this issue

Comment: @SenthilNatarajan What you are looking for is `ThreadPool`. For more information read this: http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Thread_Pooling or http://www.dotnetperls.com/threadpool

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have references to your child threads, you can just keep them in list variable:

```
ThreadStart MainThread = new ThreadStart(CallThread);
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Thread childThread = new Thread(MainThread);    
            threads.Add(childThread)
            childThread.Start();
        }
```

Comment: You can also call it directly without ThreadStart : "Thread childThread = new Thread(CallThread);"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create dynamic names for variables. The way that you are approaching is completely wrong for C#. It can be valid for a scripting language (i.e. javascript) though. Here is a small example how you can create them.

```
ThreadStart MainThread = new ThreadStart(CallThread);
List<Thread> thList = new List<Thread>(); // It will contain all the threads. If you don't need buffering threads, don't use it.
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    Thread th = new Thread(MainThread);
    thList.Add(th);
    th.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think naming Threads is what you want.

Threads can have a `Name` property. Example below:

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    TheMethodYouWantToExecute(passedVariable);
});
thread.Name = "nameThatIsAString";
thread.Start();
```

The code will create a thread using a lambda expression (*doesn't have to be*), and will start the thread you've just created.

You can add the "**thread**" variable to a `List<>` of `Thread` objects (Let's name the `List<>` "**threadList**"), and later access them by this code below:

```
var wantedThread = threadList.Where(t => t.Name == "nameThatIsAString").Single();
```

Have a nice day! If something is unclear, I'll try to explain it better.